# Symfony 4 + JMS Serializer - Internal Server Error

Tags: api, symfony, jms, symfony4, jms-serializer

I have a problem with serialization data.

I have two entities, which are connection relation.

These are my entities:

Task.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @JMS\MaxDepth(1)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="task")
     *
     */
    private $user;
```

User.php

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Task", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $task;

    public function __construct()
    {
```

I would like to create API, and I serialization my data with JMS. I get this error:

*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*

This is my controller:

```
public function getAllAction(): JsonResponse
    {
        $tasks = $this->taskService->getAll();
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
        $data = $serializer->serialize($tasks, 'json', 
        SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());

        return new JsonResponse($data, 200, [], true);
    }
```

Function *getAll* in my controller return data with table Task.

Please, help me with my problem. :)

Thanks, Friends.

Comment: Check your server log to see what's the error.

Comment: Server log, have not logs error. :(  I think that this is problem JMS serializer.

Comment: This is not a problem with JMS Serializer. I used a lot of controller beacuase I create SPA and other controller it was badly serialized. :) Thans for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not use JMS Serializer but i can suggest different solution like symfony serializer component.

```
public function getAllAction(SerializerInterface $serializer): JsonResponse
{
    $data = $serializer->serialize($this->taskService->getAll(), 'json');
    return new JsonResponse($data, 200, [], true);
}
```

Optional you can set serialization group to avoid circular reference error.

For each entity atribute that you want to serialize, set:

`use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", nullable=false, length=150)
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Groups({"group_name"})
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", nullable=true, length=255)
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 */
private $description;
```

And then you serialize only this field with specific group:

```
$serializer->serialize($this->taskService->getAll(), 'json', ['groups' => ['group_name']])
```

Doc: https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations

PS. Action suffix isnt required now
https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#controller-action-naming

Comment: mcek, Thank you for your response. :) How Can I set circular reference? :)